# insertion sorting a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, insertion-sort

I am trying to write an insertion sort method but I am unable to seal the deal.  Below is the code I have so far and I just cant seem to get the algorithm to work properly.  The RecordList class contains all the methods for the linked list.  Specificaly, `Sort()` works with a user defined object `Student` in which the students are sorted by `ID numbers`

```
public class RecordList {

    private Link first;     //ref to first item 
    private Link last;      //ref to last item
    int count = 0;          //count number of elms in list

    //constructor
    public RecordList(){
        first=null;
        last=null;
    }

    //is empty
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return first==null;
    }

    //insert first
    public void insertFirst(Student dd){
        count++;

        Link newLink = new Link(dd); // make new link
        if( isEmpty() ){ // if empty list,
            last = newLink; // newLink <-- last
        } 
        else{
            first.previous = newLink; // newLink <-- old first
            newLink.next = first; // newLink --> old first
            first = newLink; // first --> newLink
        }
    }

    //insert last
    public void insertLast(Student dd){
        count++;

        Link newLink = new Link(dd); // make new link
        if( isEmpty() ){ // if empty list,
            first = newLink; // first --> newLink
        }
        else{
            last.next = newLink; // old last --> newLink
            newLink.previous = last; // old last <-- newLink
        }
        last = newLink; // newLink <-- last
    }

    //delete first
    //ASSUMES NOT EMPTY
    public Link deleteFirst(){
        count--;

        Link temp = first;
        if(first.next == null){ // if only one item
            last = null; // null <-- last
        }
        else{
            first.next.previous = null; // null <-- old next
            first = first.next; // first --> old next
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //delete last
    //ASSUMES NOT EMPTY
    public Link deleteLast(){
        count--;

        Link temp = last;
        if(first.next == null){ // if only one item
            first = null; // first --> null
        }
        else{
            last.previous.next = null; // old previous --> null
            last = last.previous; // old previous <-- last
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public boolean insertAfter(Student key, Student dd){ // (assumes non-empty list)
        Link current = first; // start at beginning
        while(current.dData != key){ // until match is found,
            current = current.next; // move to next link
            if(current == null){
                return false; // didn’t find it
            }
        }
        Link newLink = new Link(dd); // make new link
        if(current==last){ // if last link,
            newLink.next = null; // newLink --> null
            last = newLink; // newLink <-- last
        }
        else{ // not last link,
            newLink.next = current.next; // newLink --> old next
            // newLink <-- old next
            current.next.previous = newLink;
        }
        newLink.previous = current; // old current <-- newLink
        current.next = newLink; // old current --> newLink
        return true; // found it, did insertion
    }

    //self algorithm
    public void Sort(){
        Link marker = first;
        Link current = null;
        Link temp;

        //if more than one elm sort
        if(count > 1){
            marker = marker.next;

            //outer loop
            //until end of list
            while(marker != null){
                current = marker.previous;
                temp = marker;

                //inner loop
                //until position found
                while(temp.dData.getID() > current.dData.getID()){
                    if(current == marker.previous){
                        marker = marker.next;
                    }
                    else{
                        marker = marker.next;

                        //remove temp from original position
                        if(temp.next == null){
                            last = temp.previous;
                            last.next = null;
                        }
                        else{
                            temp.previous.next = temp.next;
                            temp.next.previous = temp.previous;
                        }

                        //check to see if inserting to first elm or not
                        if(current == null){
                            //insert temp to first
                            //*****CHECK ALGORITHM*****\\
                        }
                        else{
                            //insert temp to current.next
                            temp.next = current.next;
                            temp.previous = current;
                            current.next.previous = temp;
                            current.next = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //while/else DOES not work
                else{
                    //if while condition not met
                    current = current.previous;

                    if(current == null){
                        //break to outer
                    }
                    else{
                        //break to inner
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //display
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String s="";
        Link current = first;
        while(current != null){
            s += current.dData+"\n"+"\n";
            current = current.nextLink();
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let us know the specific problem you have with the code.

Comment: when i choose to sort the order of the list dosnt change, basically all this code does nothing

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your code looks like unnecessarily complicated. Also, your code contains a lot of more code than just 'sorting' on which your question is based. If "sorting" is your point of concern, try this. ***Otherwise feel free to downvote this answer, because Stack Overflow is only here to help you clear your concepts and then debug your own code.***

This is the *short and sweet* code for Insertion sort (using array and JavaScript for easily checking in browser console). Check it in your browser console. And once you are clear with the idea, extend it for Linked List. Try to keep it simple like this and you will find your bug,

```
var a = [3,1,5,57,9,12,91,45,65,67,89,21,13,56,76,32,77,89,71];
console.log('array before sort...' + a);

//The Insertion Sort
for(var i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
  var j = i-1;
  var key = a[i];
  while(j>=0 && a[j] > key) {
    a[j+1] = a[j];
    j--;
  }
  a[j+1] = key;
}



console.log('array after sort...' + a);
```

Just press F12 to open console in your browser. Paste this code and press Enter. Play with it to understand more.

Good Luck !!!